# Jquery looping through table and making an ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table, which has name, email and priority columns.
On page load, I am looping through the table and for each table row, I am checking the priority field. If it is N, then I just display Low for that column, otherwise I have to make a service request using ajax and figure out what the priority is.
Although, it looks like I am iterating correctly, making the request correctly and getting the priority back correctly, the values are not being displayed on the column.

The ajax request returns a JSON object that has the priority.

My guess is the reason this is not working,is because ajax is a asynchronous call and by the time I got the response, I don't have the pointer to the row any more. I am not certain about this, though.

Any ideas on how to improve my code?

```js
<tr.>.each(function) {
  if($(this).find('#priority').text()=='N') {
    $(this).find('#priority').text('Low')
  } else {
    $.ajax(serviceURL
    datatype: json,
    Success: function(data) {
      if(data.priority=='A'){
        $(this).find('#priority').text('active');
      }
    } // if b ,c, etc...
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? If so, it's riddled with syntax errors. Also, it appears you most likely have duplicate ID's since your using `find` on an ID'd element.

Comment: Your guess is wrong, since you're using .each rather than a for loop. the problem has to be something else, such as one of the many syntax errors in your code.

Comment: Make a class called Priority and as you make the table give each `<td>` with for priority a unique id like `priority + index`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let's just fix up that code to get rid of some of the syntax errors and maybe shorten it a bit...

```
$("tr").each(function(){
  var thisTr = this;
  if ($(this).find('#priority').text()=='N') {
    $(this).find('#priority').text('Low');
  }
  else {
    $.getJSON(serviceURL,function(data){

      if(data.priority=='A'){
        $(thisTr).find('#priority').text('active');
      }
      // if b ,c, etc...
    });
  }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure if this will affect anything, but note the `thisTr` variable in there.  If there's any scope problem with the `$.ajax` or `$.getJSON` functions, this will hopefully fix that.

Comment: Sorry. Apologies for the errors.the table is dynamically created. Hence I do have the same ids for the columns on different rows.all I want to do is loop through the table and if the priority is not low then make an ajax call and find out the priority for that .column. In the success section, I would like to set the value of the priority column. I figured I would be able to do so,because there is only one column with that id on that row.so should $(this).find('#priority') give me that column? I have always used $.ajax to make ajax requests and am not familiar with $.getJSON

Comment: Check out `$.getJSON` on the jQuery website.  It calls `$.ajax` internally, and is generally easier to use when you're dealing with json data.

Comment: Thank you. The only thing I changed in my code was using $(thisTr).find('#priority).text('active') instead of $(this).find('#priority').text(active') and it works correctly. Arent $(thisTr) and $(this) both referrring to the same table row. Why does one work and not the other?

Comment: `this` is a special keyword, and when you call `$.ajax` or `$.getJSON`, `this` refers to something else.  That's just a scope problem that can be solved by referencing your original `this` with a variable.  In this case, you used `thisTr`